# Adjust the grid as per selected variable in filtering. Reason being even for single plot the grid size is huge

Tags: r

I tried with the below to execute my following requirement. It is working perfectly but there is some issues

When you run this code. You get 2 filter options. One is "Factors under the datasets" and other is "Filters". Now when you select values under "Factors under the datasets", the plot is displayed with many graphs. This if fine for me. But when you select dfg under "Filters" there is a single plot getting displayed. This is also fine but the issue is if you look carefully the size of the single plot is huge now and it does not look good. This is my issue. However I do take your other points that you have mentioned. Hope you got my points

```
 library(shiny)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)
 theNames <- names(df)
 MyList  <- vector(mode = "list")
 for(i in theNames){
  MyList[[i]] <- df[,i]
  }
  df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 
  5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("asd", "dfg", "fgdsgd", 
  "fsd", "gdfgd", "gs", "sdfg", "sf"), class = "factor"), B = c(29L, 
  24L, 46L, 50L, 43L, 29L, 32L, 24L, 35L, 39L, 33L, 47L, 53L, 26L, 
  31L), C = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 
  2L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gf", "gfd", 
  "gfg", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), D = c(36L, 56L, 
  39L, 26L, 56L, 35L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 45L, 34L, 27L, 43L, 40L, 56L
  ), E = structure(c(9L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
  10L, 9L, 9L, 5L), .Label = c("er", "fg", "g", "gd", "gf", "gfg", 
  "gtd", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), F = c(44L, 34L,  
  37L, 23L, 37L, 51L, 28L, 36L, 33L, 31L, 39L, 43L, 25L, 37L, 43L
  ), num = 1:15), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

  ui <- fluidPage(tags$style(
  HTML(
  "
  label {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  }
  "
  )
  ),
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel(
  "Factor_Bivariate_Analysis",
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
  fluidRow(
  column(h6(
  selectInput("se4", "Factors under the
           datasets", choices = c("", "Values"))
  ), width = 5, offset =
  0),
  br(),
  column(h6(
  actionButton("Val", "See the Values", width =
              200, offset =
              -1)
   ), width = 5, offset = 0),
   br(),
   column(h6(selectInput(
   "state", "Filters", choices = c("",MyList)
   )), width = 5, offset = 0)
   ), width =
   1000
   ),
    mainPanel(
   h5(plotOutput(
    "Plot4", width = "1000px", height =
    "1000px"
      ), width = 1000), h5(dataTableOutput("Plot5"), width = 1000)
    ))
    )))


     server <- function(input, output, session) {
     f_data <- reactive({
     wanted_case <- input$state
     cat("selected case ", wanted_case, "\n\n")
     if (wanted_case == ""){
      fd <- df
      } else {
      fd <- df %>% filter_if(.predicate = is.factor,.vars_predicate = 
      any_vars (. == 
      wanted_case))
      print(fd)
      }
      return(fd)
      }) 
       Plot4 <- reactive({
      if (input$se4 == "Values") {
      print(ggplot(data = 
 f_data(),aes(x=num,y=B,fill=A))+geom_line()+facet_wrap("A",ncol=1,nrow=8, scales = 
     "free"))
     } else if (input$se4 == "NULL") {
     ""
     } 
     })
     output$Plot4 <- renderPlot({
     Plot4()
     })
     }

     shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can we solve this issue?